# Gradle java project layout?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

I am moving from maven to gradle and as you know maven makes you have your java projects in a layout call the maven layout..

Does gradle have a layout I should be using and if so what is it

Comment: [Grade documentation, Java plugin, Project layout section](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N1222B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has. It is basically identical to Maven's layout. Of course you can customize both. And you'd know that if you tried a bit. [Java Quistart](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html) in Gradle userguide is just few clicks from http://gradle.org/ homepage.